# Questions about the finer points of HTML parsing (script, style, textarea in particular)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parsing

I'm working on an HTML parser, written in TypeScript, which can be found here:

https://github.com/kshetline/html-parser/blob/master/src/html-parser.ts

I know there are many great parsers out there already that I could use, but I have a particular interest in parsing HTML in such a way that the parser delivers information about original spacing and formatting along with semantic information. (And besides, I'm strange enough to consider writing an HTML parser a fun thing to do.)

Although it's far from done, the parser is already doing a good job of processing all of the sample HTML that I've thrown at it. But I'm uncertain about how some of the more unusual parts of parsing HTML are supposed to work — in particular, parsing the content of `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<textarea>` elements, where a lot of the usual rules don't apply.

The first question would be: Besides those three tags, are there more like them I should worry about that need special attention?

The rule *seems* to be, for all three of these particular elements, to simply grab all of the text that follows the start tag, ignoring any markup, until the matching closing tag is found, which can take the form `</matching-tag` *arbitrary amount of whitespace* `>`.

Inside `<script>` and `<style>` elements, HTML entities like `&amp;` or `&lt` will be treated as literal text. If you put `console.log('&szlig;')` in a script, the output will be `&szlig;`, not `ß`.

Inside `<textarea>`, however, entities are still interpreted even if other markup is not.

I've found some official spec info like [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-style-element):

[image: style tag specs screenshot]

...but it doesn't seem to be of much practical help. It never mentions how entities and other tags are ignored, how `<\style>` is the only thing that will terminate the content, and for all of the special attention paid to the syntax of HTML comments, a comment like this:

`<!-- Let's see if we put this </style> here! -->`

**won't stop** that closing tag from closing the style element. You end up with `here! -->` as text displayed in your browser.

So if anyone knows of any important rules I'm missing, other special tags to consider, or documentation I should read (that hopefully won't make my eyes glaze over!), the help will be greatly appreciated.